# Why is our Honey Locust tree shedding leaves and other parts?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care, honey-locust

Our honey locust is about 30 years old, 30-40 ft high.  This year it is constantly dropping "debris" onto our deck, including leaves, not yet formed leaves, pollen pods (?).  We clean it up and the next day there's a new mess. I write this in mid August but this has been going on since spring. I can't seem to find any cankers, but I'm not totally sure what to look for.  Is this tree at the end of its life?

Comment: might be a pest issue but we can't tell without photos of the tree and closeups of the debris being dropped.  Any construction close to the tree recently?

Comment: Do you live in an area with harsh winters? Did you have one last winter?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for this well-written first question! Your details are excellent, and may get you some answers, but the best way for us to help is to see your specific tree. Would you please post a picture or two? One of the whole tree, as well as something that shows what's falling off would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: That Idiot might have a great point.  Stress is different for plants than it is for humans but one will see the effects of too much stress. Honey locusts are more short lived but I don't think I'd worry.  Send pictures!  Think about purchasing a great gas blower.  Guess that is my opinion.  Anyone caring for a landscape should have a great blower and line trimmer along with a super lawn mower with extra blades.  Honey locusts are great lawn/patio trees because their leaves are so small.  August is normal for leaf drop and if you had a super hot summer an avenue of stress and excess leaf drop.

Comment: Locusts around here, a mix of black and honey, did not like the last, very mild, winter and are stressing over it now, with symptoms as you describe.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger  Good point.  Locusts are one of the toughest trees I know and if they don't get ENOUGH environmental stress, well this makes sense.  I recently ran into locusts with their normal huge thorns...'ermis'?  I love the Honey locusts inermis, but anyway, great thought!